# Find the marvelous layout

Tags: cipher, movies

Which film series is encrypted in the message below?

4 letters:

```
rdxedc - cftgyhn uytfcvbfgh cftgbhu
```

Comment: @JLee thanks for the feedback, I added some more details

Comment: I believe there are other puzzles here that use the same kind of encoding, but I'm having difficulty finding them right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The film is:

> X MEN

and this is encoded by

> drawing out the letters over a qwerty keyboard layout. For example the keys r-d-x and e-d-c on a keyboard form the two strokes of the letter X.